# GA - Users vs Sessions count

Tags: session, google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I understand than in Google Analytics a **user** is unique visitor and a **session** is a visit.

Now, when creating a new segment by **events** how is it possible that:

```
Filter Users with event category X and label Y:
> Users 31,435 and Sessions 44,562
```

and

```
Filter Sessions with event category X and label Y:
> Users 43,140 and Sessions 49,659
```

How can there be more users with the event and label by sessions than there are users that have the event and label by users?

I know the question is a bit messed up, so is the situation for me, but hopefully someone gets it!

Comment: Based on information I've been able to gather, it seems to be a malfunction of GA itself, still looking for the solution, though.

Comment: Also discussed here: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Reports/Users-vs-Sessions-count/m-p/554782